# mongo and mongodump works with auth but restore does not

Tags: mongodb, shell, terminal

Admin user permission:

```
db.getUsers()
[
    {
        "_id" : "admin.myself",
        "user" : "myself",
        "db" : "admin",
        "roles" : [
            {
                "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
                "db" : "admin"
            },
            {
                "role" : "dbAdmin",
                "db" : "reports"
            },
            {
                "role" : "dbAdmin",
                "db" : "places"
            }
        ],
        "customData" : {

        }
    }
]
```

I am able to authenticate into my remote mongo db like,

```
mongo --host <hostname> -u "myself" -p "myself" --authenticationDatabase "admin"
```

I am also able to do a dump remotely like

```
mongodump --host <hostname> --port 27017 --username "myslef" --password "myself" --out home/myself/mongodb-backup
```

But when I modify some collection on the db and try to restore it like the below code, it does not work and throws an auth error.

```
mongorestore --host <hostname> -u "myself" -p "myself" home/myself/mongodb-backup/
```

**Error:**

```
Failed: error getting auth version of server: not authorized on admin to execute command { getParameter: 1, authSchemaVersion: 1 }
```

Comment: is the same server or you are make a migration between versions?

Comment: Its the same server. And the version I use is 3.2

Comment: You tried `-db database`  at final of line? Maybe a destination db is required.

Answer (score 5):

You should add root role to your admin like this

```
db.grantRolesToUser( "myAdmin", [ "root" ])
```

And only after that you can restore from backup

Answer (score 2):

Mongo [backup docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/backup-and-restore-tools/#restore-a-database-with-mongorestore) recommend creating a specific user with the [`backup` role](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#backup) and another with the [`restore` role](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#restore).

Presumably using a user with the `restore` role, or granting the `restore` role to the user you are using at the moment would solve your problem.

```
db.createUser({
    user: "myself", pwd: "8eUEkdiKlP",
    roles: [{role: "readWrite", db: "admin"}]
});
```

Although the first link does mention that some additional privileges are required if you are trying to restore the `system.profile` collection.